# day is out of range for month error suspecting its cause of leap year

Tags: python, pandas, date, dataframe

my code doesn't seem to understand there is a leap year. The code works just fine on non leap year data. The other problem I am having is that when I print out the data the year is set to 1900 vs the actual year.

```
def processing(chunk): enter code here
    being read in (by chunksize)
    chunk['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(chunk['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d') 
    chunk['Year'] = chunk['Date'].dt.year.rename('Year') #creates a new 
        column with the year
    chunk['Month'] = chunk['Date'].dt.month.rename('Month') #new column 
        with month
    chunk['Day'] = chunk['Date'].dt.day.rename('Day') #new column with day
    chunk.drop('Date', 1, inplace=True)
return;
df = pd.read_csv('NLDN_CONUS_flash_and_cloud_2012_dT4KMG.txt', 
    delim_whitespace=True, 
    names=["Date", "Time", "Latitude", "Longitude", "Current", "Multi", 
    "Type"], chunksize=2000000, nrows=2000000)


chunk_list = []
for chunk in df:
    chunk_list.append(chunk)

df_concat = pd.concat(chunk_list)
df_concat['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_concat['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
df_concat['month-day'] = df_concat['Date'].dt.strftime('%m-%d')
df_concat['Datetime'] = df_concat['month-day'] + ' ' + df_concat['Time']
df_concat = df_concat[['Datetime', 'Latitude', 'Longitude', 'Current', 
'Multi', 'Type']]
df_concat['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df_concat['Datetime'], format='%m- 
     %d %H:%M:%S.%f')
df_concat.set_index(df_concat['Datetime'], inplace=True)
print(df_concat)
```

> ValueError: day is out of range for month

Answer (score 1):

In

```
df_concat['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df_concat['Datetime'], format='%m- 
     %d %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

you are converting to a datetime without any information about the year. So pandas assumes the default year, which is 1900.

I suggest to use the complete datetime as the index, then group by dayofyear or whatever is needed.

Comment: will that  fix the  leap year issue also?

Comment: 1900 was not a leap year. Which means: the 29. of February 1900 doesn't exist. Your error is probably because of this.